# Serilog to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: json, mongodb, .net-core, serilog

I am trying to get Serilog to log messages to a collection in a MongoDB Atlas DB, in a .Net Core API.

I need to set the connection string in appsettings.json so as to make it configurable. I am doing so like so

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MongoDB",
        "Args": {
          "databaseUrl": "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<AtlasServer>:27017/logs",
          "collectionName": "log"

        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The above does not log successfully. However, if I point it at a local instance of MongoDB, and use the same method/connection string format, then it logs.

I went through all of the steps to create the collection in MongoDB Atlas, created the collection, user and white listed the necessary IP.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone else runs into this scenario, I will post the solution to the problem, which in the end was simple, but tricky to find.

It turns out that the Serilog MongoDB Sink uses the .Net Driver version 2.3.

So, on the connection string generator in Atlas, I selected that version for .NET and it generated a connection string without the "+srv" part.

Hope that helps someone, sometime!

Comment: For the curious, a successful connection string start like:" mongodb://{userName}:{pswd}@{cluster}..." and not "mongodb+srv://{userName}:{pswd}@{cluster}...". I was able to get a successful connection str with driver version 2.4 since 2.3 "is not supported for MongoDB 3.4 and later" per the Atlas site.